# What security issues will I face when hosting a web app from home and how should I deal with them?

Tags: security, webserver, ubuntu-server, ruby-on-rails

I'm considering hosting a publicly available web application from my home with the latest [ubuntu server](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition),  the ruby on rails framework, some kind of SSL, and [mongrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongrel_(web_server)). What security issues will I face and what should I do about them? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to worry about securing the SSH I guess. `ufw` manages the firewall by default but you have to [set it up](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=823741). You can use a tool also like [Fail2ban](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/fail2ban). (Or use only known hosts, use keys for authentication AND/OR move the sshd to a different port.)

For the web part, you can only count on maintainers that they will fix security holes when there is a need for that. (Watch upgrades, upgrade when you can. That's all I guess.)